# Nginx + phpmyadmin + gitlab on one server

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, vps, gitlab

I'm not so good with nginx but i try to make somthing with that and fresh installed gitlab.

So i intall on digitalocean Gitlab. One click installer (ubuntu 13.10). But now i try to install php and phpmyadmin and after that i want to make somthing ridiculous. I want move main repository map from /home/gitlab/gitlab-satellites to main root of my dev (same server).

So gitlab need to be on my_domain.com/gitlab, and main dev server location will be my_domain.com.

Is this possible or?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Just configure your server.

Comment: i wish someone help me i try my best but no result

Answer (score -1):

you can find the nginx conf files in the gitlab installation: gitlab/nginx/etc
which will be '/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/etc' in the default install

you can then edit the .conf files as necessary

Example on the 'gitlab-http.conf' file you will find:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name git.your-domain-name.com;
```

you will have to create similar virtual hosts on NGINX for

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name your-domain-name.com;
```

OR

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name *.your-domain-name.com;
```